# Problem json_encode utf-8

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, json

I have a problem with json_encode function with special characters.

For example I try this:

```
$string="Svrček";

echo "ENCODING=".mb_detect_encoding($string); //ENCODING=UTF-8

echo "JSON=".json_encode($string); //JSON="Svr\u010dek"
```

What can I do to display the string correctly, so JSON="Svrček"?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which language is this for? I thought Perl but I'm thinking maybe PHP?

Comment: `"Svr\u010dek"` is equivalent to `"Svrček"` (UTF-8).

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6771938/209139.

Answer (score 45):

`json_encode()` is not actually outputting [JSON](http://json.org)* there. It’s outputting a javascript string. (It outputs JSON when you give it an object or an array to encode.) That’s fine, as a javascript string is what you want.

In javascript (and in JSON), `č` may be escaped as `\u010d`. The two are equivalent. So there’s nothing wrong with what `json_encode()` is doing. It should work fine. I’d be very surprised if this is actually causing you any form of problem. However, if the transfer is safely in a Unicode encoding (UTF-8, usually)†, there’s no need for it either. If you want to turn off the escaping, you can do so thus: `json_encode('Svrček', JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`. Note that the flag `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` was introduced in PHP 5.4.0, and is unavailable in earlier versions.

By the way, contrary to what @onteria_ says, [JSON *does* use UTF-8](http://www.json.org/fatfree.html):

> The character encoding of JSON text is always Unicode. UTF-8 is the only encoding that makes sense on the wire, but UTF-16 and UTF-32 are also permitted.

---

* Or, at least, it's not outputting JSON as defined in [RFC 4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt). However, there are [other definitions of JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18419503/209139), by which [scalar values are allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19570682/209139).

† JSON may be in UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UFT-32LE, or UTF-32BE.

Comment: +1 for JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE

Comment: What's the alternate for 5.2

Comment: Do you actually need `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`, @MuhammadBabar? If you're not using UTF-8, you don't *want* it. If you are using UTF-8, you still don't *need* it: using it will make your output *slightly* smaller, that's all.

Comment: Yes i need it and i'm using UTF-8. The question was regarding escaping unicode to return the actual chatacters. Though i did found a solution. Thanks and cheers

Comment: @MuhammadBabar What was the solution?

Comment: @Ted use this function `function replace_unicode_escape_sequence($match) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');` like this `preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', 'replace_unicode_escape_sequence', $json);` also you may need to save your script file as `UTF-8` encoded!

Comment: Your best option, @Ted, would be to upgrade PHP to a version which supports `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`. However, as I said before, the escaped version is perfectly valid and really shouldn't cause any problems. I'm curious why anyone would need to do this.

Comment: Please note that `json_encode` does not emit escaped Unicode code points.  For example `json_encode('Hello José ")` produces the horrible `"Hello Jos\u00e9 \ud83d\ude31"`.  U+D83D and U+DE31 are not legal Unicode code points. So it is emitting the horrible, horrible UTF-16 code units. It has erred in confusing logical code points with physical encoding layouts, an abstraction violation seen again and again in places like Java and C# and Windows.

Comment: @tchrist. [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38463038).

Comment: You're one of those types that are completely right, but where you just hate the answer anyway.
var_dump always showed it correctly, had no clue I had to configure json_encode to anything. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Ok, so, after you make database connection in your php script, put this line, and it should work, at least it solved my problem:

```
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `json_encode` escapes non-ascii characters. If you decode it you'll get your original result:

```
$string="こんにちは";
echo "ENCODING: " . mb_detect_encoding($string) . "\n";
$encoded = json_encode($string);
echo "ENCODED JSON: $encoded\n";
$decoded = json_decode($encoded);
echo "DECODED JSON: $decoded\n";
```

Output:

```
ENCODING: UTF-8
ENCODED JSON: "\u3053\u3093\u306b\u3061\u306f"
DECODED JSON: こんにちは
```

***EDIT***: It's worth nothing that:

> JSON uses Unicode exclusively.
>
> The self-documenting format that
>   describes structure and field names as
>   well as specific values;

Source: http://www.json.org/fatfree.html

It uses Unicode ***NOT*** UTF-8. This FAQ Explains the difference between UTF-8 and Unicode:

http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8

You use JSON, your non-ascii characters get escaped into Unicode code points. For example [こ = code point 3053](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3053/index.htm).

Comment: Incorrect. [JSON does use UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10835469/209139).