# Any way to return PHP `json_encode` with encode UTF-8 and not Unicode?

Tags: php, unicode, json

Any way to return PHP `json_encode` with encode UTF-8 and not Unicode?

```
$arr=array('a'=>'á');
echo json_encode($arr);
```

`mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');`and `$arr=array_map('utf8_encode',$arr);` does not fix it.

Result: `{"a":"\u00e1"}`

**Expected result: `{"a":"á"}`**

Comment: UTF-8 _is_ Unicode

Comment: UTF-8 is not Unicode, but rather one possible encoding of it.

Comment: @fromvega: Nonsense. UTF-8 is an encoding scheme. Unicode is a directory that assigns meaning to numbers.

Comment: Is the `\u` escape causing you problems for some reason (it shouldn't: any JSON decoder must be able to cope with it correctly). Or are you just trying to save a few bytes of transfer?

Comment: @bobince - to save some bytes.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. What I meant was precisely what you already said, that UTF-8 is one of the standard character encodings of Unicode.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`{"a":"\u00e1"}` and `{"a":"á"}` are different ways to write the same JSON document; The JSON decoder will decode the unicode escape.

In php 5.4+, php's `json_encode` does have the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` option for plain output. On older php versions, you can roll out your own JSON encoder that does not encode non-ASCII characters, or use [Pear's](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON/download) JSON encoder and remove line 349 to 433.

Comment: i've php version 5.6.21. but not working this.utf8_encode() did the trick for me.

Answer (score 44):

I resolved my problem doing this:

- The .php file is encoded to ANSI. In this file is the function to create the .json file.
- I use `json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)` to encode the data;

The result is a .json file encoded to ANSI as UTF-8.

Comment: ANSI is ... not really a thing. Do you mean Windows-1252?

Comment: What a simple solution! It's working great! You have saved may day! :)

Answer (score 31):

This function found [here](http://www.avoid.org/?p=67), works fine for me

```
function jsonRemoveUnicodeSequences($struct) {
   return preg_replace("/\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/e", "iconv('UCS-4LE','UTF-8',pack('V', hexdec('U$1')))", json_encode($struct));
}
```

Comment: No need of it since `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`.

Comment: @Binyamin, yes, but not everyone runs php 5.4

Comment: I tried this solution and it didn't work as i needed, but found another that solved my problem at [Convert Unicode from JSON string with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523846/convert-unicode-from-json-string-with-php), hope it helps anyone that needs it.

Comment: Yeah, this didnt work for me either. The result was way too many backslashes, so instead of "ÖXXX" I got "\\\ÖXXX". If I removed the json_encode at the end, I got "\ÖXXX", so one backslash too many.

Comment: **This doesn't work if** the input contains a string which contains a JavaScript Unicode Escape Sequence. For example, for the input string `"\u0059"`, applying `jsonRemoveUnicodeSequences()` gives `""\Y""` (which is invalid JSON), then applying `json_decode()` gives `NULL` instead of the original string.

Comment: `/e` for `preg_replace()` is [*deprecated* in PHP 5.5.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php).

Answer (score 11):

Use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`  inside `json_encode()` if your php version >=5.4.

Answer (score -4):

just use this,

```
utf8_encode($string);
```

you've to replace your `$arr` with `$string`.

I think it will work...try this.

Comment: Utf8_encode() needs to be done before json_encode().

It will not solve the above issue alone.