# Parse JSON as UTF-8

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, utf-8

I'm using the following code to get JSON from a page and parse it to my HTML page. The JSON is not being displayed in UTF-8 and therefore has weird characters. How can I remove the weird characters?

```
$.get("test.php", function (data) {
    var JSON = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $.each(JSON.deals.items, function (index, value) {
        // My code
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you post an example of your JSON?

Comment: heres a link that generates the json http://oxhey.wc.lt/test.php

Comment: Are you referring to the unicode characters in the `title` properties? Eg `\u00c2\u00a314.99`? If so, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901133/json-and-escaping-characters) may help, however it would better to change the encoding on the server if possible.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thats not possible

Comment: im using file_get_contents in the php file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please make sure that every single step of your process is in UTF-8:

- The database connection
- The database tables
- Your PHP file
- The content-type headers that you output

  `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`

  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Refer to: [PHP json_encode json_decode UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076988/php-json-encode-json-decode-utf-8)

**EDIT**: If you already have weird characters like `\u00a3` in your JSON feed instead of the `£` symbol, your problem has already been answered: <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423846/convert-unicode-from-json-string-with-php</s>

Comment: there is no database . The php file has the content type header

Comment: Well,  assuming you're referring to the weird characters and escaped slashes in your data, your PHP file is getting it's data from somewhere, and this data is already not UTF-8... so your problem lies in wherever this PHP file get's its data from.

Comment: right , but i cannot change that . is there a way to remove the characters after?

Comment: You are referring to the weird characters like `\u00a3` which should be £? If so, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523846/convert-unicode-from-json-string-with-php . Your problem has already been asked there, and has already been solved as well. I have updated my answer so you can select it as the correct one.