# How to return {"a": "\u0002"} to browser in php?

Tags: php

I want to send some data to browser, I write code like below.

```php
<?php
$arr = array('a'=> "\u0002 hello");

exit(json_encode($arr));
?>
```

and I get a result：
[image]

but I wanna a result like below, \u0002 not \\u0002, what should I do?
[image]

Comment: `"\u0002"` in PHP is not the character with code 2 (why do you use it?) but a string that contains ``\``, `u` and the four digits.

Comment: Encoding your given data as JSON, _must_ escape this backslash. If you want to get only `\u0002` _in_ your JSON - well then you need to provide the _proper_ input data that json_encode would transform into this to begin with.

Comment: What do you actually want to send? If you want a string that contains `\u0002` and you send it JSON encoded then the \ must be escaped. It's not clear though if your intention is to literally send `\u0002` or if you have some other character in mind

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22745662/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/6771938/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/7381900/2943403

Answer (score 2):

`"\u0002"` in PHP is not the character with code 2 (why do you use it?) but a string that contains `\`, `u` and the four digits.

Use the [`chr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr) function to produce a character from its numeric code.

```php
$arr = array('a'=> chr(2)." hello");
echo(json_encode($arr));
```

Check it [online](https://3v4l.org/I38XJ).

Answer (score 1):

`\u####` is JSON's unicode escape format, and has no meaning in a PHP string.

Using PHP's actual unicode escape:

```php
$arr = array('a'=> "\u{0002} hello");
```

Or, since codepoints below `128` / `0x80` have single-byte representations, you can get away with:

```php
$arr = array('a'=> "\x02 hello");
```

Both will produce the desired output: `{"a":"\u0002 hello"}`