# Rails JSON Import - unicode characters detected

Tags: php, json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have thousands json files created from a old php application that will be imported into a new version being developed in rails.

In php i'm running `json_encode($object)` to encode the item before saving it.

Here is a edited down version of the json that is being produced. The description field is where I'm seeing the unicode character.

`{ "ID": "", "parentID": "", "formID": "", "defaultProject": "", "data": { "title": "", "idno": "", "date": "2016-11-09", "creator": [ ], "contributor": [ ], "itemNumber": "", "oclcNumber": "", "publisher": "", "publisherLocation": "", "description": "<..contents removed> family\u00e2\u0080\u0099s land <..contents removed> \r\n", "subject": [ ], "type": "", "provenanceDpla": "", "rights": "", "location": [ ], "timePeriod": "", "format": [ ], "language": [ ], "source": "", "extent": "" } }, "metadata": "", "idno": "", "modifiedTime": "", "createTime": "", "modifiedBy": "", "createdBy": "", "publicRelease": "" }`

The part that we are having issues with is in the description field. The original looks like.

[image]

When I view the imported record this part looks like.

[image: garbage characters]

Inspecting the item in the rails console that looks like this.

[image]

I'm using `@hash = JSON.parse(File.read(file))` does anyone have a good recommendation on how to handle this. I'm sure we will find this more as we work on exporting the content.

Comment: What is your definion of "handle it"? To convert the files to UTF-8?

Comment: These look like noise from legacy systems as some of these characters are [<control> characters](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/) and you maybe be able to clean them. For more context, could you share a snippet of these json files? Also, which encoding these files are using?

Comment: `0xE28099` is the UTF-8 representation of the right-single quote https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm

Comment: @Tracy, I'm not quite sure the problem. Is it that you are getting Unicode escape sequences, and your Ruby JSON parsing logic isn't unescaping them for you?

Comment: I updated my question with additional information and what I'm seeing in the item and what I see in the view.

Comment: @TracyMcCormick try encoding the json in php using `json_encode($object, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)` [ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13478887/1042324]

Comment: @daniloisr I just tried that and re-imported that didn't change anything.

Comment: @TracyMcCormick I see, let's try finding out which encoding PHP is using so we can use Ruby's `String#encode` to fix it. Try https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php oh PHP so see what it returns for `$object->description`

Comment: @TracyMcCormick also, try checking the encoding of the .json file with https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/uchardet. The problem seems that Ruby is trying to read the file as utf8 but it isn't, because `\u00e2\u0080\u0099` should be just `\u2019` in utf8. I tried many different ways of encoding `\u00e2\u0080\u0099` as `\u2019` in Ruby, but no success until now

Comment: In the php export I was trying to prepare the data by doing `$utf_encoded = mb_convert_encoding( $item, 'UTF-8' );` removing this it now gives me the code `\u2019` instead. It imported correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the php export I was running `$utf_encoded = mb_convert_encoding( $item, 'UTF-8' );` to insure that everything was encoded as utf-8 but for some reason this was producing the above result. Removing this gave me a unicode of `\u2019` instead of `\u00e2\u0080\u0099` which importing into the new rails app worked correctly.