# PHP - Database results encoding?

Tags: php, json, encoding

i have the following function to obtain a language strings, it works fine for english but not for portuguese characters.

```
public function GetAllLanguageStrings($langid)
    {
        $GLOBALS['mysqli']->query("use " . $GLOBALS['db_name']);
        $stmt = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->prepare("SELECT lang_identifier, text FROM lang_strings WHERE lang_id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $langid); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($identifier,$text);
        $result = array("LangStrings" => array());

       while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            array_push($result['LangStrings'], array("Identifier" => $identifier, "Text" => $text));
        }

        return json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

the results turn out to be wierd

```
{ "Identifier": "LOGIN_INFORMATION", "Text": "Informa\u00e7\u00f5es de Login." }
```

instead of

```
{ "Identifier": "LOGIN_INFORMATION", "Text": "Informações de Login." }
```

i tried to add the following settings:

```
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag might be what you are looking for.

Please refer to [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058450/problem-json-encode-utf-8) for details on how json_encode outputs data and how to manipulate the output by setting the right flags.

Comment: better than before but still:
{"Identifier":"LOGIN_INFORMATION","Text":"InformaÃ§Ãµes de Login."},

Comment: well is the text stored as utf8 im the db?

Comment: look slike it: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00E7/index.htm you actualy end up with the correct encoded value. Does the webserver return utf8 encoded content? check the headers.  Is there another charset specified in the document?

Comment: The solution:
return utf8_decode(json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));

still i'm marking your answer as correct because you helped out ;)

Answer (score 0):

```php
return utf8_decode(json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```